# View PDFs with Chromium on Windows

Tags: windows, pdf, chromium

It's possible?

Is there a way to install the plugin?

I've been searching trying to find a solution for this, but found nothing.

Edit: Without installing anything from Adobe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Adobe Reader on the computer. The PDF will then display in Chrome.

Comment: Edit: it's possible without installing anything from Adobe?

Comment: You could try installing another PDF reading product. Otherwise no, your only other option is to serve images.

Answer (score 5):

1. Grab the "pdf.dll" from the latest Google Chrome version. ([Download here from version 25.0.1364.172](http://www.mediafire.com/?ekdeyb7km9varni))
2. Put it in Chromium's install directory ("C:\Program Files\Chromium\Application" or "%appdata%/Chromium/Application/VersionNumberHere/")
3. Restart any running instance of Chromium.
4. Type "chrome://plugins" in Chromium, make sure the plugin is enabled and any other PDF plugin is disabled.
5. And test your browser in: [http://www.google.com.br/search?q=pdf+test](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=pdf%20test)

Comment: Can I distribute my Chromium build with same solution?