# Chromium build with pdf-viewer

Tags: windows, google-chrome, pdf, chromium

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591639/1035099 I can get `pdf.dll` from installer Google Chrome and make Chromium build, that can view pdf-files.

Can I distribute my Chromium build with `pdf.dll` from Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. It is a component that Google licensed from a third party.